# Is it safe to scan debit card's front and back side for my broker?

Tags: debit-card, broker, online-payment

To make a deposit, my broker, regulated by EU and established, asks me to provide the scans of the front and back side of the debit card.

"Name, expiration date and the first and last four digits of the credit card number must be visible - other sensitive information may be hidden."

Please, is it safe to scan debit card's front and back side for my broker?

And are there any sensitive information that I should hide (apart from the ones required by the broker).

Thank you

Comment: You're making the deposit using funds from the card, correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's safe to reveal the first and last four digits of your card number -- that's not considered to be confidential data. And of course your broker already has your name,, so letting them have a scan of it doesn't disclose any new information. You should make sure to obscure the CVV code (the last three digits of the number on the back of the card).

Answer (score 1):

Your broker has to be considered a trusted financial intermediary, and as such you have to trust their confidentiality.

Is it safe? No, but the liability is on them to keep your information confidential.

Is there a viable mature alternative? No.

Comment: In the US, I'd give the broker direct access to a bank account via electronic funds transfer, rather than through a debit card. (Paypal also likes to operate that way.) If nervous, I'd use a seperate account for that purpose and run my own eft's between that and my "real" accounts. I'm not sure that's ans safer, or less safe, than your approach.

Comment: @keshlam that is a decent strategy, as long as you consider the separate account compromised. The problem still remains that someone could social engineer a situation involving your account to get more things done in your name or possibly steal from you

Answer (score 1):

Obscure everything except that which is required to be visible. In that case your broker has told you exactly what they need to see, just show those items.  Also, don't just digitally manipulate the picture. Use a reasonably solid matter, duct tape on paper for instance, to block the scan from seeing the other information.